# Redirect to same page after POST method using class based views

Tags: django

I'm making a Django app that keeps track of tv show episodes. This is for a page on a certain Show instance. When a user clicks to add/subtract a season, I want the page to redirect them to the same detail view, right now I have it on the index that shows the list of all Show instances.

**show-detail.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'show:addseason' show=show %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">+</button>
</form> 

<form action="{% url 'show:subtractseason' show=show %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">-</button>
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
class ShowDetail(DetailView):
    model = Show
    slug_field = "title"
    slug_url_kwarg = "show"
    template_name = 'show/show-detail.html'

class AddSeason(UpdateView):
    model = Show
    slug_field = 'title'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'show'
    fields = []

    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.season += 1
        instance.save()

        return redirect('show:index')

class SubtractSeason(UpdateView):
    model = Show
    slug_field = 'title'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'show'
    fields = []

    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        if (instance.season >= 0):
            instance.season -= 1
        else:
            instance.season = 0

        instance.save()

        return redirect('show:index')
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),

url(r'^about/$', views.AboutView.as_view(), name='about'),

# form to add show
url(r'^add/$', views.ShowCreate.as_view(), name='show-add'),

# edit show
#url(r'^(?P<show>[\w ]+)/edit/$', views.ShowUpdate.as_view(), name='show-update'),

# delete show
url(r'^(?P<show>[\w ]+)/delete/$', views.ShowDelete.as_view(), name='show-delete'),

# signup
url(r'^register/$', views.UserFormView.as_view(), name='register'),

# login
url(r'^login/$', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),

# logout
url(r'^logout/$', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),

url(r'^error/$', views.ErrorView.as_view(), name='error'),

url(r'^(?P<show>[\w ]+)/$', views.ShowDetail.as_view(), name='show-detail'),

url(r'^(?P<show>[\w ]+)/addseason/$', views.AddSeason.as_view(), name='addseason'),

url(r'^(?P<show>[\w ]+)/subtractseason/$', views.SubtractSeason.as_view(), name='subtractseason'),

url(r'^(?P<show>[\w ]+)/addepisode/$', views.AddEpisode.as_view(), name='addepisode'),

url(r'^(?P<show>[\w ]+)/subtractepisode/$', views.SubtractEpisode.as_view(), name='subtractepisode'),
```

I get an error when I try

```
return redirect('show:detail')
```

This is the error

```
NoReverseMatch at /Daredevil/addseason/
Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Answer (score 69):

For CBV:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)
```

For function view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
```

Comment: Please, what do you mean by " path_info "? Is it the path name?

Comment: `path_info` is a variable stored in request. It has the current url that you're on. It's just like reloading the page.

Comment: wouldn't `path_info` store the CBV url (i.e /subtractseason in OP's example) whereas OP wants to go back to the URL that the user is 'on' (not the URL that was hyperlinked to the item that was clicked)

Answer (score 24):

You can achieve this by redirecting to `HTTP_REFERER` header and for fallback just add another path.

Example snippet:

```py
return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', 'redirect_if_referer_not_found'))
```

Comment: Is there a way we may send the `HTTP_REFERER` bit from the view to the template say, picking its value by someting like `redirect_frm = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')` and send `redirect_frm` to the template?

Answer (score 20):

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def someview(request):

   ...
   return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12758859/14020019

Comment: Please do not repost an existing answer, when you'll have enough reputation you'll be able to flag question as duplicate.

Comment: This answer worked great for me - simple and direct. OP wants to go back to the URL that the user was 'on'

Answer (score 18):

to redirect to the **same page** (e.g. an http GET) after a POST, I like...

```
return HttpResponseRedirect("")   # from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
```

it also avoids hardcoding the `show:detail` route name, and is a lil' clearer intention wise (for me at least!)

Comment: What if I want to send some data too, such as a dictionary? How to achieve this?

Comment: It opens to a **blank** page!!

Comment: I'm getting a blank page as well

Comment: Looks like this no longer works. The answer was originally given in 2016.

Comment: return HttpResponseRedirect("#") seems to be a replacement in Django ~3.2.  I put it in as a placeholder in my code, and behold, it worked!

Comment: I'm on Django 3.2.10 and it works in chrome

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing you need to provide a kwarg to identify the show when you redirect, although I can't see the code for your `DetailView` I would assume the kwarg is called either `pk` or possibly `show` going from the convention you've used in `AddSeason` and `SubtractSeason`. Try:

```
redirect('show:detail', kwargs={'show': instance.pk})
```

**EDIT:** the name of the detail url is `'show-detail'`, so the scoped viewname would be `'show:show-detail'` (if it is in the `show` namespace like the other urls). I still think it would need a kwarg though, try:

```
redirect('show:show-detail', kwargs={'show': instance.pk})
```

Comment: Hey, I tried that it didn't work. I included my show-detail view. Please help me out if you can.

Comment: What's the error you get, is it the same? Can you post your urlpatterns?

Comment: Same error, and edited my post to show my urlpatterns!

Comment: Edited the answer, see above, you can try with or without the `kwargs` kwarg

Comment: Got this error    Reverse for 'show-detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<show>[\\w ]+)/$']

Comment: It is finding the correct urlpattern now. Did you try with kwargs? If that doesn't work, try `redirect('show:show-detail', args=(instance.pk, ))`

Comment: Yes, I did try with kwargs. Now I tried that solution, and it's still not working. Thanks for helping though.