# what can I return in Django Views.py function, if I dont want to return anything?

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am working on a project using Django where I am creating a login authentication. I have created a function in `Views.py` (login) and I don't want to return anything, so I tried returning `none`. This yields an error, so what can I return instead?

Comment: Simply `return HttpResponse()`

Comment: Why do you want to use views in case you do not want to render anything on the template. Even in case you are processing some POST data or something like that you should redirect to some page or else do not create a view at all create a normal function in the same file

Comment: no, I dont want to redirect I just want to be on that page  even after successful login, Thanks For Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The view returns an HttpResponse object that contains the generated
> response. Each view function is responsible for returning an
> HttpResponse object.

Answer (score 0):

view on django has default return

```
`from django.http import HttpResponse

    def my_view(request):
    return HttpResponse(status=201)`
```

visit docs for more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/views/

Comment: or `return HttpResponse()`

Comment: but what it does is redirect me to a blank page, but I want to be on the same page without reloading.

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39560175/10002142