# how to realise redirect to same page in Django views?

Tags: python, django

I am writing an online store in Django.
How do I redirect to the same page?
This is needed to remove an item from the popup cart.
The delete from cart function:

```
def cart_remove_retail(request, slug):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug)
    cart.remove(product)
    return  #???
```

when i try:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
```

I get round-robin query.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you need to redirect, but you need to refresh data from db. Try to add this: `request.session.flush()` befor return

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def cart_remove_retail(request, slug):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug)
    cart.remove(product)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Taken from : [Redirect to same page after POST method using class based views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39560175/redirect-to-same-page-after-post-method-using-class-based-views)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to redirect to the page where the request to cart_remove_detail is originating, you can use

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
```

Alternatively add a next parameter to the request to cart_remove_detail.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to the same page in django view you can use :

```
return redirect('.')
```

Comment: thanks for you're answer! but with this construction i still have a 'Cyclic redirects on the page'