# How to add an extra button to "Change List" page in Django Admin for the particular model in particular app?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-admin

So, I want to add an extra button in my `Fun` model's changelist_view which when pressed, performs a function and redirects me to a new page. I don't want to have this function for every app nor do I want for every model, only the `Fun` model. And I will be using Django Admin to view this changelist, just a side note.

Can anyone suggest anything? Thanks.

Comment: You can use [admin actions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/actions/)

Comment: Thank you for your comment Pedram Parsian. I've already considered that but I was looking for a physical `button` that I could click on (Like a button next to the add button) to perform my action.

Comment: So you can _customize_ the `change_list_template`, add your button and link that to your view. Basically, you should add something like `<a href="{% url 'your_url' %}">My Button</a>`

Comment: Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of using Django Admin? Could you show a working example in the answers?

Comment: Is it possible to add override the template for only a specific Model or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codes in **fun/admins.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Fun


@admin.register(Fun)
class FunAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = 'fun/admin_changelist.html'
```

and for the **fun/admin_changelist.html** template:

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_static admin_list %}

{% block result_list %}
  <a href="{% url 'your-url-name here' %}">The custom button</a>
  {% if action_form and actions_on_top and cl.full_result_count %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
  {% result_list cl %}
  {% if action_form and actions_on_bottom and cl.full_result_count %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Overriding the admin templates is perfectly fine, but replacing them (completely) is not recommended; So we will just override the part that we need (here I assume your button will be located in the top of the list, so I only override the `result_list` block)

Then you should have url with `name="your-url-name here"` that is connected to a view.

Check the docs for [more details](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates)

Comment: Aaah! That neat. Thank you Pedram. Also, how could I perform an action when I click the button? Like let's say I want to `print("Button Pressed")` when the button is pressed. How would I do that?

Comment: When the button is clicked, it will run the code inside the associated view for a url named `your-url-name here` (see template code). So you can put your code there.

Comment: Let me know if you can't get it working as you want.

Comment: Thank you Pedram, you've helped me a lot. But here's just a single tad thing I don't understand. Since I only want to execute a function and stay on the same page, I don't understand how work this out. Do I create a view, put my function in it, as soon as it's complete, redirect back to my page?

Comment: @AnthonyMartinez Yes, you shoud redirect back to the same page - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12758786/9733868); and if you don't want to see the page _refreshing_ when you click the button, you can use **ajax calls**.

Comment: And there we go. You have saved my soul. Thank You for your time Pedram

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra buttons to **Change List** page only for a particular admin(model) in a particular app, then redirect to **Change List(Current)** page.

For example, there is `Person` model as shown below:

```py
# "app1/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

And, there is `Person` admin as shown below:

```py
# "app1/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name')
    list_editable = ('first_name', 'last_name')
    list_display_links  = None
    ordering = ('id',)
```

And, this below is **Person `Change List` page**:

[image]

Now, copy [pagination.html](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#templates-which-may-be-overridden-per-app-or-model) from `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/pagination.html` in your virtual environment to `templates/admin/app1/person/` to add extra buttons to **Change List** page only for `Person` admin in `app1` as shown below. *To add extra buttons to **Change List** page for all admins in all apps, copy `pagination.html` to `templates/admin/` and for all admins in `app1`, copy `pagination.html` to `templates/admin/app1/` and you can see the original [pagination.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/pagination.html):

```
Django Project
 |-core
 |  └-settings.py
 |-app1
 |  |-models.py
 |  └-admin.py
 |-app2
 └-templates
    └-admin
       |-app1
       |  |-person
       |  |  └-pagination.html # Here
       |  |-animal
       |  └-fruits
       └-app2
```

Then, add `<input ... value="{% translate 'Lowercase' %}">` and `<input ... value="{% translate 'Uppercase' %}">` after `<input ... value="{% translate 'Save' %}">` in `pagination.html` as shown below:

```
# "templates/admin/app1/person/pagination.html"

# ...

{% if cl.formset and cl.result_count %}
<input 
  type="submit" 
  name="_save" 
  class="default" 
  value="{% translate 'Save' %}"
>
{# ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ Here ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ #}
<input
  type="submit" 
  name="_lowercase" 
  style="background-color:yellowgreen;margin-right:5px;"
  class="default" 
  value="{% translate 'Lowercase' %}"
>
<input
  type="submit" 
  name="_uppercase" 
  style="background-color:yellowgreen;margin-right:5px;"
  class="default" 
  value="{% translate 'Uppercase' %}"
>
{# ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ Here ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ #}
{% endif %}
</p>
```

Then, override [changelist_view()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.changelist_view) in `Person` admin as shown below. *You can see the original [changelist_view()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1935):

```py
# "app1/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
csrf_protect_m = method_decorator(csrf_protect)

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name')
    list_editable = ('first_name', 'last_name')
    list_display_links  = None
    ordering = ('id',)

    @csrf_protect_m # Here
    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        to = '/' + '/'.join(request.build_absolute_uri().split('/')[3:])

        if "_uppercase" in request.POST:
            for obj in self.get_queryset(request):
                obj.first_name = obj.first_name.upper()
                obj.last_name = obj.last_name.upper()
                obj.save()
            return redirect(to)

        if "_lowercase" in request.POST:
            for obj in self.get_queryset(request):
                obj.first_name = obj.first_name.lower()
                obj.last_name = obj.last_name.lower()
                obj.save()
            return redirect(to)
        return super().changelist_view(request, extra_context)
```

Then, you can make all first and last names uppercase or lowercase, then save by clicking on `Uppercase` or `Lowercase` buttons respectively then, redirect to **Change List(Current)** page as shown below:

[image]

[image]