# Using Django views to redirect the user to the page they took the POST action on:

Tags: django, redirect, django-views

A user could be at one of three pages:

For this argument let's call them page1, page2 or page3.

On each of those pages, they can take the same actions essentially, with subtle differences. So if the user is on page1 and they take a POST action, then after the post action is done, the redirect should just "refresh" the page so they remain on page1 and can conduct other business from there.

In the view, how do I call the URL and then return redirect(that_url)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect / return to same (previous) page in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758786/redirect-return-to-same-previous-page-in-django)

Comment: That does help actually, thanks. I looked at it before and perhaps didn't read it properly. But that is helpful. Thank you.